# Getting the English Word for Mac

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

I accidentally downloaded the Italian (at least I think it's Italian?) Word for Mac, do you know how I can get an English version? I've been searching online for a while and I only was able to get English dictionaries for it.

Comment: Try buying it. If you got the wrong language version, try contacting your vendor.

Comment: I think you can download an add-in language pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Office softwares are sold as separate products for each language, so you cant change it into a different language. Your best bet would be to contact your distributor and ask if they have a trade-in program of something like that and buy the English version of the software.